# How to remove the warning below in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem I have is that it is giving me a warning in mysqli stating this:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in ...on line 89
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

```
$questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(an.Answer ORDER BY an.Answer SEPARATOR ' ') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
       q.QuestionMarks 
  FROM Answer an 
  INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
  JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
  JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

                 WHERE ";

$i=0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {     
    $i++;         

    if ($i == 1){         
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";     
        } else {         
            $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";    
             } 
             }  

             $questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY "; $i = 0; foreach ($terms as $each) {     
                 $i++;      

    if ($i != 1)         
    $questionquery .= "+";     
    $questionquery .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)"; 
    } 

    $questionquery .= " DESC "; 

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery);      
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $each = '%' . $each . '%');
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionId,$dbQuestionContent,$dbOptionType,$dbNoofAnswers,$dbAnswer,$dbReplyType,$dbQuestionMarks); 
    $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows();
```

OUTPUT OF SQL:

```
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(an.Answer ORDER BY an.Answer SEPARATOR ' ') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks 

FROM Answer an INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 

WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? 

GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId 

ORDER BY IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0) DESC
```

Comment: [Seriously, try fulltext search.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106155/fatal-error-is-causing-no-results-to-appear-mysqli#comment14547138_11106155) This is exactly the situation a fulltext search is intended for.

Comment: I still need help on this question if anyone can please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confused MySQLi's parameter binding method with PDO's (which accepts an array to `execute()`.  Call [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) on `$each` and pass no parameter to `execute()`.

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $each);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that if you intend to use `LIKE` queries with `%` wildcards, those wildcards must be part of the bound variable, such that:

```
$each = '%' . $each . '%';
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your theory but the problem is that it is now giving me a different warning. I have updated question to show what new warning says and updated code as well.

Comment: @user1421767 Please post the full sql statement as you are preparing it in `$questionQuery`. You will need to have as many `s` and vars in the final bind as you have `?` in the SQL.

Comment: The full sql statement is in the code I have provided but to make readability easier I have provided full sql statement at bottom of question

Comment: @user1421767 You misunderstand me.  Please post the output of `echo $questionQuery;`  so we can see exactly what the SQL you have constructed looks like before you execute it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have included the output of $questionquery in the question above :)